# Orders of field automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: field-theory, automorphism-group

It is well known that, given the axiom of choice, $\mathbb{C}$ has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ field automorphisms. Except that the non-obvious automorphisms cannot be constructed explicitly, can we say more about them? Specifically, is there one $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ with finite order $>2$ (that is, $\sigma^n = \mathrm{id}$ for some $n>2$ but $\sigma^2 \neq \mathrm{id}$) ? Does every finite order occur? Is there one $\sigma$ with infinite order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you stuck at constructing some $\sigma$ with infinite order?

If finite then the order is $2$, this is explained in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf .

With $\rho$ the complex conjugaison, every $\sigma \rho \sigma^{-1}$ has order $2$, this gives infinitely many examples.

There are also order $2$ automorphisms that are not of this form (for example the one of $\Bbb{C}((x))/\Bbb{R}((x))$ conjugated with an isomorphism $\Bbb{C}((x))\to \Bbb{C}$)

Comment: Thanks! I think I've worked out the infinite order case. We have $\mathbb{C} \cong \overline{\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \cdots)}$ because both have characteristic $0$, cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ and are algebraically closed. Pick a $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \cdots))$ that permutes $\{x_1\}$, $\{x_2, x_3\}$, $\{x_4, x_5, x_6\}$, $\{x_7, x_8, x_9, x_{10}\}$, ..., then $\sigma$ is of infinite order, and it can be extended to $\mathrm{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, \cdots)})$ since a homomorphism to an algebraically closed field can be extended to the algebraic closure.

Comment: And the finite order case is explained in the Page $5$ of the link.

Comment: @JianingSong More natural to pick an automorphism of say $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/n},e^{2i\pi /n})$ of infinite order and to extend it to $\Bbb{C}$ using axiom of choice